# Getting the localtime in milliseconds

Tags: c, datetime, time

I need the fastest way to get the localtime (thus considering the current timezone) at least in milliseconds precision, if is possible to get in tenths of milliseconds it would be better.

I would like to avoid the use of `gettimeofday()` as it is now an obsolete function.

So, there seems that I'll need to use the `clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, ...)` and adjust the hour to the current timezone, but how ? And where is the best point to do that ? Before to store the timestamp got with clock_gettime, or before to convert it in a gregorian calendar in the current timezone?

**EDIT: My original sample joining get_clock and localtime** - There are better ways to reach that?

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    struct timespec ts;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);

    struct tm* ptm;
    ptm = localtime(&(ts.tv_sec));

    // Tenths of milliseconds (4 decimal digits)
    int tenths_ms = ts.tv_nsec / (100000L);

    printf("%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d.%04d\n", 
        1900 + ptm->tm_year, ptm->tm_mon + 1, ptm->tm_mday, 
        ptm->tm_hour, ptm->tm_min, ptm->tm_sec, tenths_ms);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's a better way than with `clock_gettime()` and `localtime()`. However you need to round the returned nanoseconds correctly and consider the case when the time is rounded up to the next second. To format the time you can use `strftime()` instead of formatting the `tm` struct manually:

```c
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    struct timespec ts;
    long msec;
    int err = clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);
    if (err) {
        perror("clock_gettime");
        return 1;
    }

    // round nanoseconds to milliseconds
    if (ts.tv_nsec >= 999500000) {
        ts.tv_sec++;
        msec = 0;
    } else {
        msec = (ts.tv_nsec + 500000) / 1000000;
    }

    struct tm* ptm = localtime(&ts.tv_sec);
    if (ptm == NULL) {
        perror("localtime");
        return 1;
    }

    char time_str[sizeof("1900-01-01 23:59:59")];
    time_str[strftime(time_str, sizeof(time_str),
            "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", ptm)] = '\0';

    printf("%s.%03li\n", time_str, msec);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this can be achieved using the `clock_gettime()` function. In the current version of POSIX, `gettimeofday()` is marked obsolete. This means it may be removed from a future version of the specification. Application writers are encouraged to use the `clock_gettime()` function instead of `gettimeofday()`.

Long story short, here is an example of how to use `clock_gettime()`:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L

#include <inttypes.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void print_current_time_in_ms (void)
{
    long            ms; // Milliseconds
    time_t          s;  // Seconds
    struct timespec spec;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &spec);

    s  = spec.tv_sec;
    ms = round(spec.tv_nsec / 1.0e6); // Convert nanoseconds to milliseconds

    printf("Current time: %"PRIdMAX".%03ld seconds since the Epoch\n",
           (intmax_t)s, ms);
}
```

If your goal is to measure elapsed time, and your system supports the "monotonic clock" option, then you should consider using `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` instead of `CLOCK_REALTIME`.

One more point, remember to include `-lm` flag when trying to compile the code.

To get the timezone, just do the following:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE /* for tm_gmtoff and tm_zone */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
  time_t t = time(NULL);
  struct tm lt = {0};

  localtime_r(&t, &lt);

  printf("Offset to GMT is %lds.\n", lt.tm_gmtoff);
  printf("The time zone is '%s'.\n", lt.tm_zone);

  return 0;
}
```

**Note:** The seconds since epoch returned by `time()` are measured as if in GMT (Greenwich Mean Time).

Comment: But, what about the current timezone adjustment ?

Comment: I have edited my answer for your query related to timezone. It gives you a code to get the timezone. Now how to adjust it as per your requirement is left to you as an exercise.

Comment: Thanks. I've edit the question to show my original test, which motivated me to ask this question, I really need to know how is the more recommended (fast) way to reach that.